# -[IgzHelper doneWithNumberPad]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1923c230'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i created my helper class, it returns UIToolbar and my issue is this error 
"**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[IgzHelper doneWithNumberPad]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1923c230'**"

```
//#IgzHelper.h

-(UIToolbar *)createDoneForNumberPad:(SEL)sel;


//#IgzHelper.m

-(UIToolbar *)createDoneForNumberPad:(SEL)sel{

UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:sel],
                       nil];
numberToolbar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];

return numberToolbar;

}
```

THIS CLASS "AccountSettingViewController"
IS CALLING igzHelper createDoneForNumberPad

THIS IS THE CODE "SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH GUY PLEASE HELP ME"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.phoneNumberTF.inputAccessoryView = [igzHelper createDoneForNumberPad:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)];
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{

  [self.phoneNumberTF resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a crash because the `IgzHelper` don't know about the method `doneWithNumberPad`. this methode is defined in the `AccountSettingViewController` but you are telleing to your toolBar that it is defined in the `IgzHelper`.

```
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:sel],
                       nil];
```

You are putting the target to `self` witch is the `IgzHelper` but the methode is défined in `AccountSettingViewController`.

Put the method in `IgzHelper`or change the target to be the `AccountSettingViewController`class:

```
-(void)doneWithNumberPad{

  [self.phoneNumberTF resignFirstResponder];

}
```